# HighCharts export is printing my page and chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a wordpress site where I have a chart and when I hit print prints the page where the chart is and the chart in the same page but the chart is outside the container instead of printing the chart by itself as its supposed to. Because you can see that the code is working , because you can see how all the elements get removed and the lone chart is left on the page. Yet it does not print the way it was intended to.

[Here](http://hastebin.com/fihoyiyihi.xml)is a copy of the page I am trying to print from.

Comment: So all works properly or not, because I feel a little but confused.

Comment: Its no working on the site http://shrp2dev.bt-systems.com/?attachment_id=316# try to print a chart

Comment: Well, you mean map chart or other?

Comment: @SebastianBochan The chart is not printing by itself as is supposed to. Instead prints the all the non-displayed elements and the chart below those elements. That's what I mean.